# Какую кодировку нужно устанавливать в MySQL

Tags: mysql

На сайте http://www.webpupil.ru/view_server.php?id=4 нашел информацию о настройке БД. Там говорится о том, что надо установить кодировку cp1251 вот так:
В раздел [mysqld], после строки port=3306 необходимо добавить следующие строки:

character-sets-dir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/share/charsets"
 
default-character-set=cp1251
character-set-server=cp1251
init-connect="SET NAMES cp1251"
 
skip-character-set-client-handshake
Но я сомневаюсь, что надо установить именно эту кодировку, т.к. слышал, что везде ставится кодировка utf-8.
Вопрос какую кодировку надо выставить: utf-8 или cp1251 или, может быть, еще какую-то? И вообще при установке MySQL надо ли выбирать кодировку cp1251 или надо выбрать что-то другое

Comment: такие сайты я делал в 2000-ых. не стоит доверять интернету - лучше почитайте официальную документацию

Comment: мануал из 2005-2008 годов

Comment: @eri "такие сайты я делал в 2000-ых. не стоит доверять интернету". Что Вы имеете в виду? Что не стоит ставить кодировку cp1251, потому что она древняя или что?

Comment: @eri можете, пожалуйста, дать ссылку? А то я понятия не имею где искать этот мануал :\

Comment: устанавливать надо кодировку **utf8mb4**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing.html

Comment: @Ипатьев ок. Я правильно понимаю, что чтобы установить utf8mb4 нужно просто в данном случае заменить во всех строка cp1251 на utf8mb4?

Comment: Нет. Все эти шаманские пляски вообще не нужны. Кодировку надо задавать при создании таблиц и при установлении соединения.

Comment: @Ипатьев а, хорошо, спасибо. Но еще вопрос: Вы говорите надо писать utf8mb4, но у меня в книге после установки соединения с помощью mysqli_connect() идет функция mysqli_set_charset(), в которой кодировка задается как "utf-8". Получается можно и utf8mb4 писать, и utf8, и не будет никакой разницы? Или всё же разница в чем-то есть?

Comment: если в книге так и написано,  "utf-8", то ее надо выбросить, порвать и сжечь. Если написано , "utf8", то она написана еще до твоего рождения, и надо просто взять что-нибудь посовременнее. Разница в том, что utf8mb4 это нормальная кодировка.

Comment: @Ипатьев жОскА) Ясно, спасибо)

Comment: utf-8 - это название стандарта. utf8 - это устаревшая реализация этого стандарта в mysql, не поддерживающая кучу символов. utf8mb4  - нормальная реализация стандарта.

Comment: @Ипатьев ок, понял

Comment: cp1251 пользуют только слоупоки (вроде авторов таких сайтов и книг) и поехавшие фанатики, которые, судя по всему, покупали жёсткий диск последний раз лет двадцать назад и которым жалко тратить по два байта на русские символы (серьёзно, я встречал несколько таких). В 2019 году нужно использовать только utf8mb4 однозначно без вариантов. // С реализацией utf8 в MySQL накосячили (ограничение не более 3 байт на символ, а многие спецсимволы хотят 4 байта), а уже сильно позже сделали некосячную реализацию, но её пришлось назвать utf8mb4, потому что название utf8 уже было занято косячной реализацией

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кодировку надо устанавливать **utf8mb4**.

- cp1251 - это кодировка, которая устарела еще в прошлом веке.
- UTF-8 - это название стандарта, который уже много лет используется во всем мире
- utf8 - это устаревшая реализация этого стандарта в mysql, не поддерживающая кучу символов
- utf8mb4 - нормальная реализация стандарта

Все эти шаманские заклинания "В раздел [mysqld]" писать **нельзя**. Код должен быть переносимым. и работать на любом сервере, а не только на своем домашнем компике.

Поэтому кодировку надо задавать при создании таблиц и при соединении с БД.